# Querying multiple tables in BigQuery (without using _TABLE_SUFFIX)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select certain columns from multiple tables. The names of the tables are different so I cannot use the _TABLE_SUFFIX in the WHERE clause, i.e. this SQL does not work.

```
SELECT
user_id,
property_1,
property_2
FROM `database.dataset.*`
WHERE  _TABLE_SUFFIX  like "table_name_something"
       OR _TABLE_SUFFIX   like "table_name_something_else"
       OR _TABLE_SUFFIX   like "yet_another_table"
```

Could anyone advise a different approach?

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to use sharded tables if the table names are different.. you'll have to use the old fashioned method of "union all".

Comment: That's what I ended up using. Thanks!